# Tool for calculating co-occurrence matrix of words for NLP task

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

I have a 15gb text of words. I need to calculate the co-occurence counts of words in fixed size of window and then work on them. For example, here is my text;

"foo says hoo, bar says what?"

To construct bigram with co-occurrence frequencies from this text for window size = 4 the output should be the following;

word1-word2-count

foo,says,1

foo,hoo,1

foo,bar,1

says,hoo,2

says,bar,2

says,says,1

hoo,bar,1

hoo,what,1

bar,what,1

says,what,1

I already know there are tools for doing this such as NLTK but it is not multithreaded, so will not work for texts in size 15gb. Is there any tool that can give me the co-occurrence matrix of words in a given window size and in fast way?

Answer (score 2):

I have looked for such a tool myself but have never found it. I usually simply write a script to do it. Here is a sample with some *limitations* that might be of use to you:

```
import concurrent.futures
from collections import Counter

tokens = []

for _ in range(10):
    tokens.extend(['lazy', 'old', 'fart', 'lying', 'on', 'the', 'bed'])


def cooccurrances(idx, tokens, window_size):

    # beware this will backfire if you feed it large files (token lists)
    window = tokens[idx:idx+window_size]    
    first_token = window.pop(0)

    for second_token in window:
        yield first_token, second_token

def harvest_cooccurrances(tokens, window_size=3, n_workers=5):
    l = len(tokens)
    harvest = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_workers) as executor:
        future_cooccurrances = {
            executor.submit(cooccurrances, idx, tokens, window_size): idx
            for idx
            in range(l)
        }
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_cooccurrances):
            try:
                harvest.extend(future.result())
            except Exception as exc:
                # you may want to add some logging here
                continue


    return harvest

def count(harvest):
    return [
        (first_word, second_word, count) 
        for (first_word, second_word), count 
        in Counter(harvest).items()
    ]


harvest = harvest_cooccurrances(tokens, 3, 5)
counts = count(harvest)

print(counts)
```

You should see this if you just run the code:

```
[('lazy', 'old', 10),
 ('lazy', 'fart', 10),
 ('fart', 'lying', 10),
 ('fart', 'on', 10),
 ('lying', 'on', 10),
 ('lying', 'the', 10),
 ('on', 'the', 10),
 ('on', 'bed', 10),
 ('old', 'fart', 10),
 ('old', 'lying', 10),
 ('the', 'bed', 10),
 ('the', 'lazy', 9),
 ('bed', 'lazy', 9),
 ('bed', 'old', 9)]
```

**LIMITATIONS**:

- This script will not handle well large token lists because of the slicing
- The chopping up of the `window` list works here but you should be aware of it if you intend to do anything with the window list slice
- You may need to implement something specific to replace the `Counter` object in case that chokes (again large list limitation)

**WILD GUESS**:

You may be able to write something like this using the `spaCy` `Matcher` (see [here](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/rule-based-matching)), however, I am not sure this will work just yet as the wildcards you will need are still a bit shaky (in my experience).